# Controlling clang diagnostics

Tags: clang

I have the following situation when compiling with clang:

```
r300_state.c:716:44: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 9, have 5
                tex->tex.stride_in_bytes[0]);
                                           ^
```

This doesn't really tell me the name of the function that expects the 9 arguments and is in such form not much of help.

Can I somehow tell clang to print more lines of source code when errors (or even warnings) occur?

Comment: Please provide more information, including a complete source code snippet which can be compiled, and full compiler output. When I run similar code through clang, I also get a "note: 'my_func' declared here" pointing at the function.

Comment: You're right. It seems that I totally missed the note part.